# Spark scala : Append String to Dataframe's Existing Column according to condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with two columns as below

[image: OutliersDF]

Now I want to check in Outliers column if 'col' == 'city' then the corresponding 'reco'=Sancak (assign the Recommendation column value to it)
[image: ExpectedResult]

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Hi Prachi, Please add sample data in json format code so that once can easily copy and construct dataframe. You have pasted images. To achieve this you need to perform map transformation on your dataframe and for each row

Comment: Outliers Recommendation
[{'col':'city','reco':'Sancak'},{'col':'country','reco':''}] Sancak
[{'col':'city','reco':'Chicksands'},{'col':'country','reco':''}] Chicksands                                                                                          
 Can you write the code for map transformation here?